# nginx will not serve images from windows server

Tags: nginx, windows-server-2008

I have a couple web apps that run on my windows server.  I have installed nginx on  ubuntu and used the reverse-proxy to serve the web apps from the windows machine.  The nginx is serving the apps, but not images.  I can access the apps directly by ip and port from outside and they work fine.

I get this error in the error.log for each image:

[crit] 29174#29174: *3034 open() "/var/lib/nginx/proxy/6/18/0000001186" failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: myurl.net, request: "GET /framework/dimmer@2x.png HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.168.1.50:8008/framework/dimmer@2x.png", host: "myurl.net", referrer: "https://myurl.net/"

Please let me know of any additionasl info that would help.

Comment: Hi, please add detail, any log file that show a error while serving the images, the folder securty set, etc..

Comment: Please see the updated post.  Thanks